# Why doesn't tensorflow's go/ subdirectory use go_library from Bazel rules_go?

Tags: go, tensorflow, bazel

The README in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/go describes a build process that's a bit disjointed.

Why not use SWIG and the go rules in https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go?

Comment: You would have to ask the authors of that library.

Comment: Posted here at the request of the authors of that library, so they could answer it in a public, accessible format

Comment: This is not the appropriate forum for that - if they want to explain their design decisions, that should be posted to their own project space, not on StackOverflow. This question, and its answer, are not useful to the broader community.

Comment: I see, that's too bad. I would disagree that the question and answer aren't useful to the broader community. Bazel and the rules_go repository are young projects that are seeing increasing popularity. Using other Google projects, like TensorFlow, to understand what the proper way to apply concepts from Bazel and rules_go seems like a good way to learn. My question is intended to understand whether or not the technique used in TensorFlow's go subfolder should be imitated elsewhere. Based on the answer below, it appears that it should not be. But I am certainly not an authority on SO. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no good reason for this, other than "historical accident". Tensorflow had Go code before rules_go was very mature, so they implemented their own rules.

I've worked on rules_go full time for the past several months. Our main priority this year has been to support Kubernetes' migration to Bazel by building out the features they need and making the rules simple to use. When that effort is completed (soon), we'll move on to supporting other projects using Bazel and Go more directly. I hope this will include Tensorflow.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I'm working on integrating a large Go project with TensorFlow, so I'd be happy to help when the time comes.